# PayPal direct payment issue

Tags: java, payment, credit-card, paypal

I am making use of Paypal for billing in my app. I have successfully done with Express Checkout in production. Now for user not having Paypal account I want to have "pay with credit card option" now here I have to ask two things;

**First**: In Pakistan (upon calling express checkout page)Paypal window showing the credit card option if you dont have an account but not in UK and Germany ( I tested in these two regions) why it is so and what the work around?

**Second**: I have implemented Direct payment which needs Website Payment Pro to be enabled.and I have designed the whole screen which takes credit card info  from user and then call `doDirectPayment()` which is not trustful from user's point of view ,so is there any other way to get payments with credit cards on a paypal hosted page for security and trustful transaction?

assistance required
Cheers

Comment: On your 2nd question...if your customers don't trust to do direct payment (which is exactly that - paying directly from your site), then...loop back to Express Checkout :)

Comment: @EdSF do u think its fine experience as a user :) ??

Comment: I don't know, only your users can answer that question based on actual use and/or feedback. What "difference" is a "hosted" page and Express Checkout at the end of the day? Express Checkout is a "hosted" page by a trusted name (PayPal) where your users can then choose to pay however they deem fit. You can do "classic" or ["in context"](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/) as well.

Comment: @EdSF sir thnx alot to pointing me to another feature "in context" , will look it surely...but Express checkout is all fine ... I m only stuck with credit cards, data security and trust :( ... I think need to do a lot more work to handle this huuh..

Answer (score 0):

For Express Checkout, you can set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in your API call to PayPal to indicate that you want Guest Checkout ("PayPal Account Optional") to be available for that checkout attempt. However, the exact behavior will vary from region to region and from customer IP to customer IP. PayPal's risk and fraud checks as well as broader country regulatory rules will sometimes require users to create an account during checkout.

The alternative is direct payment, where the customer supplies their credit card to your site instead of through a PayPal-branded checkout. This is only available for business accounts in select countries and requires approval and is subject to PCI compliance rules as with any direct credit card processing service.

Comment: thnx for ur reply, i have applied for WPP..but little confusion do we need SSL certificate or https for that page where we are taking these credite card credential..I am jus a noob

Comment: Yes. HTTPS is not a PayPal requirement, but it is a PCI compliance requirement.

Comment: once again thnx alot for ur response....i haven't deal with any of the two, well some more to research and learn.....  :&